# Query label values that had a specific value in the past

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I wanted to build a Grafana dashboard to analyze failed canary releases in Flagger. Flagger provides a metric `flagger_canary_status` that shows the status of a canary. The status is encoded the following:

| Value | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Canary currenly running |
| 1 | Canary suceeded |
| 2 | Canary failed |

So I would like to select into a Grafana variable the name of the apps that had a failed canary currently and potentially later within the currently shown range.

Using the query `label_values(flagger_canary_status, name)` it returns all label values for the metric (so I have a list of all the canary apps, not only the failed ones), but when I query like this: `label_values(flagger_canary_status == 2 , name)` it fails with the error "Error updating options: 1:23: parse error: unexpected <op:==>" though `flagger_canary_status == 2` alone is a valid prometheus query.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I am now using the a recording rule to record a metric only when the canary status has the value 2. The avg_over_time is used, so the metric stays on that value 1h after canary was fixed (meaning the value went back to 1)

```
  groups:
    - name: "flagger-recording-rules"
      rules:
        - record: flagger_canary_with_problems_last_hour
          expr: avg_over_time( (flagger_canary_status == 2) [1h:10m])
```

The solution is not so flexible as if I just had the query in Grafana, but it works as intended